# Wait action to finish before starting the next one

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a game.

I made a function for each direction my character can move, and then I tried making a function to make the character walk the whole track, by calling the other functions inside it.

```
function fullMotion() {
  moveRight(365);
  moveUp(300);
  moveRight(570);
  moveDown(300);
  moveRight(365);
}
```

The problem is as it is right now the character makes all 5 movements at once, and I want him to first go to the right, then after this action finish go up and so on until the end.

I googled a lot trying to find a way, but all the solutions I found looked way too complicated for such a simple problem, most using promises or callbacks; and I imagine there's probably a super simple solution that I couldn't find.

Thanks.

```
Movement functions are:

function moveSkeleton0Right(){
    let left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(skeleton0).getPropertyValue("left"));
    left += 1;
    skeleton0.style.left = left + "px";
}

function moveRight(i) {
    if (i < 0) return;

    setTimeout(function () {
        moveSkeleton0Right();
        moveRight(--i);

    }, 16);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's just not being executed faster than you expect?

Comment: See async functions (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and `setTimeout` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: Could you include the code for your move functions?

Comment: I think you need to look into a JS game library of some kind.

Comment: I'm sure they're not being executed too fast, when I call each one individually they work just fine, but when I call the full one the character doesn't even go up or down, just right, so I'm assuming he's actually going both up and down at the same time and one cancel each other out, as all 5 movements are happenning at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know how much animation last i.e. one second so:

```js
function fullMotion() {
  setTimeout(()=>moveRight(365),0);
  setTimeout(()=>moveUp(300), 1000);
  setTimeout(()=>moveRight(570), 2000)
  setTimeout(()=>moveDown(300), 3000);
  setTimeout(()=>moveRight(365),4000);
}
```

Comment: Using setTimeout to wait for something to happen is not a good solution. If timing ever changes, your code breaks. Also, javascript's setTimeout is not exact. You aren't guaranteed that your callback will execute exactly what you want it to. So it creates things like race conditions and unpredictable execution.

Comment: While not a optimal solution, it made it work for now, so thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Sure, it's not perfect @Cully. Also your move* functions can return a promise object and you can await on those events but it realy depends on how move* implementations are, it they are browser/css related you can rely on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event

Comment: With all due respect due cully  I agree with  JoãoFranciscoMagalhães. Yes it is not optimal, but at least it does work for the purpose. As @João mentioned he did not want to go through promises and callbacks, may be the time does not allow him to look at it at this time. He knows what he needs. May be the work he is doing does not require it. And because of that user1432711 answered the question this way.

Answer (score -1):

```js
async function fullMotion() {
  await moveRight(365);
  await moveUp(300);
  await moveRight(570);
  await moveDown(300);
  await moveRight(365);
}
```

One be one way of implementing asynchronous functions here (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: The OP's move functions don't return promises, so your code wouldn't work.